# OpenGL: Copy Contents Of Display List

Tags: opengl, rendering, snapshot, displaylist

I am stuck on OpenGL 1.1 for a particular game-modding project, and I am using a display list as a sort of snapshot of part of the game, where I begin the display list, direct those parts to render, and close the display list. This correctly results in a display list I can then transform and render at will.

However, while I am transforming and rendering that display list, the part of the game that was snapshotted ceases to exist, and it destroys any display lists that it had been using, meaning when I render my snapshot, those parts that were display lists then fail to render.

What I would like to be able to do is somehow direct OpenGL to copy the contents of nested display lists into the top-level one instead of just embedding the call to the nested display list. I haven't been able to find any function that would do what I want. Does one exist?

(No, the parts of the game I am snapshotting are not predictable, and are likely to be wildly different every single time.)

Comment: Why do you want to copy the contents to a top-level display list?  For convenience?  Or performance?  If the latter, note that display lists were deprecated in OpenGL 3.1.  They're not the most efficient way to drive the video card anymore -- for that see [Vertex Buffer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object).  If you're using display lists you might as well just create a function that calls your nested display lists and call that from the top level.

Comment: @maackle: I think you're missing the point here. OP is modding an existing game engine and there's little that can be done to change the internal workings of the engine.

Comment: I don't think this is such a good idea, to be honest. If you do not capture the full state machine setup you are only getting a very small piece of a much larger more complicated puzzle. One example that comes to mind immediately has to do with the polygon front face winding; you could be capturing all of the vertices in the proper order but come to find that they are culled because you don't have full set of states that were in-place when those commands were originally issued. You might have to wrap the underlying API with a custom DLL (the good news is, you don't need to support extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to hook into all relevant OpenGL calls, by injecting a "opengl32.dll" hooking DLL with entry points identical to the OpenGL ones, but each one making a copy of the relevant data.